# HTTPERR filling up, fast with Timer_ConnectionIdle

Tags: iis, logging, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5

We have 2 web servers that have used up over 100GB of logging in C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR.  Is there a standard way for disabling this logging as it's just filled with Timer_ConnectionIdle.

I'd like to disable this via Group Policy if at all possible.

The servers in question are running Windows Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 9):

As per the [KB 820729](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/820729)

Timer_ConnectionIdle : The connection expired and remains idle. The default ConnectionTimeout duration is two minutes.

Timer_ConnectionIdle, happens in normal HTTP protocol usage, where the client decides not to disconnect from the server because there is a good chance that it will have another request for the server either in the process of loading a page or because a client will probably click a link on a web page that will go back to the same server. By default the server will close the connection and reclaim those resources after 2 minutes of inactivity. This is nothing to worry about, it's just an informational type of entry.

I hope you do have 180 seconds of default timeout setting configured in IIS. You can use the article [Configuring HTTP Server API Error Logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364457%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to completely disable HTTP.sys logging (not recommended) but there is no way to disable a particular event.

Comment: I think the default is 120, which is what it is set to.

Comment: sorry yes, 120 seconds

Answer (score 3):

There is a very fast and easy way to completely disable it; add the following value to the registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters]
"EnableErrorLogging"=dword:00000000
```

Then stop and start the HTTP service to apply the changes:

```
net stop http
net start http
```

Source: [Error logging in HTTP APIs](https://support.microsoft.com/nl-be/help/820729/error-logging-in-http-apis)